# Get from tablerow same values with previous variable - php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql

facing a problem, will try to make as clear as possible. Trying to fetch data from mysql, but do not understand the logic of it.
I want to make an input where people write their name (for example "aa" or "bb" in this case) and they get a result that are grouped by same "unique_order".

As you can see in in this picture below, I have a table that containes who and unique_order:

[image]

I made an input where people can get their data by inserting their "who".
Baically this is what I want to achieve - fetch all rows by name "bb" and group them separatly by "unique_order":
[image]

I can simply do this by:

```
$who = $_POST['search'];
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE `who` = "$who";
AND
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE `unique_order` = "1";
```

But there will be a lot of "unique_orders" (1, 5, 15, 33, 594 etc..) and I want to make this auto, how is this possible to achieve?

After the successfull query I want to make a:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ 
<<<table information>>>
}
```

so I can duplicate these as there are unique rows from name "bb";

EDIT:
So I found solution by help of one of the answers below, is there are a cleaner way of doing this?

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ordrs WHERE `who` = 'bb' GROUP BY unique_order";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$queryResult = mysqli_num_rows($result);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ 

    echo $row['unique_order'];
    $unique_order_columns =    $row['unique_order'];



    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM ordrs WHERE `unique_order` = '$unique_order_columns '";
    $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
    $queryResult2 = mysqli_num_rows($result2);
    while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)){ 
    echo "<div style='color:red;'>";
        echo $row2['id'];
        echo "</div>";
    
     }



 }   ?>
```

[image]

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE who = '$who' GROUP BY unique_order` does this solve your problem? or `SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE who = '$who' ORDER BY unique_order ASC` if you want to fetch all rows

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this query

SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE `who` = "$who";

And then use login in php

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ 
   <<<table information>>>
if($row['unique_order']==1){
    //handle 
}else if($row['unique_order']==2){
     //handle 
}else if($row['unique_order']==3){
    //handle
}
```

Comment: Not a valid solution. There will be probably 1000+ rows, also, I gave "1, 2, 3 etc." as an example, in production, it will be a long random string, for example ac48re61er5, but if if fetches information automatically, there's no difference what the string is.